# How can I launch the Maps app from Mobile Safari on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I want to launch the maps application from my mobile website.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use simple HTML links; iOS will recognize and open it.

Here is the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1) you need.

Hope it helps!