# When I link to Google Maps on a website, Mobile Safari opens the Maps app but doesn't zoom correctly

Tags: google-maps, mobile-safari

This is a follow up to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614096/how-can-i-launch-the-maps-app-from-mobile-safari-on-an-ios-device).  Issue is I link to something like http://maps.google.com/?daddr=49.89793,-97.20494 and the location is passed correctly however the map is fully zoomed out so I see all of North and South America.  I have tried adding a couple different parameters to the URL but none seem to be working.  "z=13" sets the zoom to 13 but not on mobile, only a full URL like http://maps.google.com/?daddr=49.89793,-97.20494&z=13

Answer (score 1):

Zoom seams to work on a mobile in combination with the q-Parameter, only:

http://maps.google.com/?q=49.89793,-97.20494&z=13

Since using daddr (Destination Address) is waiting for a saddr (Start Address) to determine the zoom level.

Comment: Is there a way to pass current location to saddr?  That may be helpful

Comment: Why not just set the point to daddr then? Maps gives the user the option to use the current location as saddr.

Comment: read the question, that's what I am doing but it is zoomed out all the way

Comment: I guess you have to choose then between setting the q parameter, with the map zoomed in. Or setting the daddr, where the user can easily start navigation from his current locataion, but having the map zoomed all the way out.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Mobile Safari, you can pass

```
saddr=Current+Location
```

and Google Maps will use the current location to provide routing options and set the map scale.